# Visual Studio/TFS - Is there a way to prompt when a new version is checked in?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I'm looking for a way to prompt a user when a new version of a project they're working on is checked in. I've gathered that there is a way to automatically Get Latest Version but it was removed from later versions of Visual Studio in part because it's considered bad practice.

What I would like to be able to do is prompt the user (rather than doing it automatically) with the option to Get Latest Version - or merge their work, probably - if the version they're working from is older than the newest checked in version. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I'm fairly certain there's no way to do this within Visual Studio (if I'm wrong in this, please let me know) but is there a way to write a script or something that uses something like the VS/TFS command line commands to perform the check and throw the prompt to the user?

Thanks!

Comment: curious to know what problem you're actually trying to solve.  are you having merge issues because developers aren't merging often enough? or is it a problem further down the track?

Comment: It's actually a simpler issue than it should be... We have developers that forget to Get Latest Version before working on code more than anything else. We get an occassional issue where a developer checks out code and begins working then another developer checks out that code for a different reason and finishes the work before the first person finishes theirs and we get merge conflicts.

Comment: You could simply run a timer with reminder for the people who struggle. That way you build a habit of getting latest instead if reinforcing the bad behaviour

Answer (score 2):

This is really a training issue. Every Developer should do a get latest before they start coding, and before they commit.

This is a basic practice and removes the need for complex customisations.

Answer (score 1):

In TFS, you can work with alert systems to subscribe alerts when there is one new version for controlled files. Subscribers will have one email, and they will determine whether to get the newer version based on their requirement.

You can subscribe to get the alert with the Checkin alert category:
[image]

Please check this MSDN article for the details on configuring TFS alerts: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334.aspx

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to see if this will work for us.